# mysqld_safe is causing problems at login

Tags: mysql

I'm running ubuntu 10.04 and recently have installed mysql server 5.1
but when i tried to log in, it showed me an error like this:

```
can't log in to mysql server through /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

But last day I tried to kill all mysql processes and start again ,and when I killed mysqld_safe ,surprisingly I managed to log in and perform queries on mysql server through

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Now I want to ask if I can disable `mysqld_safe` for ever.

Comment: [Have tried this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69380/my-mysql-installation-is-broken-how-to-completely-reconfigure-it/69450#69450)